# GC does not free memory, but causes decrease in managed and increase in unmanaged memory

Tags: .net, linux, kubernetes, memory, garbage-collection

I have an ASP.NET Core application running on Linux (in Docker, on Kubernetes). I am running into the situation where my fully managed application uses 5 MB on the GC heap, but the application reserves 5 GB (and will consume more until it is killed via OOM). I collected a memory dump using dotMemory and I can see that the memory is consumed by unmanaged memory. I get the same picture by calling `GC.GetTotalMemory` vs `Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64`.

[image]

The code is fully managed mostly reading files, processing them, and storing the processed data in a database. I use `DevArt.PostgreSql` but also tried `Npgsql` and it makes no difference. I also use a single raw, persistent `Socket` connection. In the given test case, there are no calls to Web API on ASP.NET Core. `dotMemory` does not show any managed leaks in those library, nor in my part of the code.

Memory Usage will look like this:

`Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64=582 MB / GC.GetTotalMemory=372 MB`

and after a while jump to

`Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64=600 MB / GC.GetTotalMemory=5 MB`

I can force this collection using the following code:

```
GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
```

So, I can conclude more than 300 MB were transferred from GetTotalMemory to WorkingSet64. I don't see how else to arrive at those numbers. When memory fills up again, it can look like this:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64=1375 MB / GC.GetTotalMemory=4 MB
(few moments later)
Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64=1433 MB / GC.GetTotalMemory=1081 MB
```

In this case, a lot of GC memory could be reclaimed from the WorkingSet. However, this cycle is never perfect and the increase in WorkingSet64 goes up until 50+ GB and the process is killed due to OOM.

The machine has high Core Count (32) and RAM (64 GB). I tried both variants of GC, but made no difference.

Somehow, the memory is just not released back to the OS.

Here's my LOH
[image]

Here's my 2nd generation
[image]

Gen 0 and 1 are empty.

Any suggestions how I might find the root cause would be appreciated.

Comment: I seem to have the same issues. Did you find any workarounds?

Comment: There was a piece of code that created an incredibly large amount of small objects. I refactored this code, used object pools and smarter algorithm that creates only 10% of the objects. In that way, a lot of the memory consumption went away. What was the root cause though I never found out. I cannot pin point a logical issue with the code. It obviously just wasn't GC friendly... not a very satisfactory situation.